# Parallel execution with StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: c#, performance, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a 1M items store in `List<Person>` Which I'm serializing in order to insert to Redis. (2.8)

I divide work among `10` `Tasks<>` where each takes its own section ( *`List<>` is thread safe for readonly* ( *[It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*)

**Simplification :**

example:

For  `ITEMS=100`, `THREADS=10` , each `Task` will capture its own PAGE and deal with the relevant range.

For exaple :

```
void Main()
{
    var ITEMS=100;
    var THREADS=10;
    var PAGE=4;

    List<int> lst = Enumerable.Range(0,ITEMS).ToList();

    for (int i=0;i< ITEMS/THREADS ;i++)
    {
      lst[PAGE*(ITEMS/THREADS)+i].Dump();
    }
}
```

- `PAGE=0` will deal with : `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`
- `PAGE=4` will deal with : `40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49`

All ok.

Now back to SE.redis.

I wanted to implement this pattern and so [I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viRIl.jpg) : (with `ITEMS=1,000,000`)

[image]

My testing :

(Here is `dbsize` checking  each second) :

[image]

As you can see , 1M records were added via 10 threads.

Now , I don't know if it's fast but , when I change ITEMS from `1M` to `10M` --  things get *really* slow and I get exception :

The exception is on the `for` loop.

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. ---
>
> > System.TimeoutException: Timeout performing SET urn:user>288257, inst: 1, queu e: 11, qu=0, qs=11, qc=0, wr=0/0, in=0/0    at
> >     StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message
> >     messa ge, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in
> >     c:\TeamCity\buildAgen
> >     t\work\58bc9a6df18a3782\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultip
> >     lexer.cs:line 1722    at
> >     StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message,
> >     ResultProces sor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in
> >     c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\58bc9a6df
> >     18a3782\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisBase.cs:line 79
> >     ... ... Press any key to continue . . .

**Question:**

- Is my way of  dividing work  is the RIGHT way  (fastest)
- How can I get things faster ( a sample code would be much appreciated)
- How can I resolve this exception?

Related info :

`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />` Is present in App.config ( otherwise i'm getting outOfmemoryException ) , also - build for x64bit, I have 16GB ,  , ssd drive , i7 cpu).

Comment: Which bit is it doing when it fails? The bit at the top (`ParallelEnumerable`)? or the bit inside the `fore` loop? It really wouldn't amaze me if the top bit failed, but that is nothing to do with SE.Redis.

Comment: @spender yes, the SE.Redis `IDatabase` instance is fully thread-safe and is intended for heavily concurrent access

Comment: @MarcGravell Sorry for not mention that , the ParallelEnumerable works fine. it start crashing in the `for` loop ( after a while)

Comment: Do you have the bit in yellow as a [pastie](http://pastie.org/) or similar? Basically, something I can run?

Comment: @MarcGravell http://jsbin.com/kesujalu/2/edit ( dont forget to add the allow big object things in app.config)

Comment: @spender that is pure speculation; I see no reason to suspect that as related

Comment: What server are you using, and what memory allocator is *it* using? I'm wondering if this is actually simply the allocator at the server slowing down. Also: re faster - I suspect I can make it quite a bit faster with a one line change: `db.StringSet("urn:user>" + element.Id, element.ToJSON(), flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget);`

Comment: @MarcGravell im using it with my win 8 computer , no server . Thanks for helping. Can i make it work ?(10m)

Comment: @RoyiNamir by "server", I mean the `redis-server` instance. You can use `info memory` via `redis-cli` to see the allocator; I get `dlmalloc-2.8` when running the current `Redis-64` NuGet package

Comment: @MarcGravell , same as yours  http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVCaW.jpg

Comment: Yes it's just a pressure test to play with , at the moment , but still - i dont understand why it fails

Comment: Well so far, all I can succeed in doing is killing the redis-server process (presumably out-of-memory)...

Comment: @MarcGravell strange.....  Myne —  _used_ to crash when I did not allow the big object thingy  in the config file  ... I also built it for 64 bit.... I have no clue why the _server.exe_ is crashing,,,,

Comment: Does it always fail at the same 'place'? Have you tried limiting the number of operations firing per second per thread, i.e. a bit of throtling?

Comment: Note that although there is an identifier called THREADS in this example there are no threads but rather Tasks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Currently, your code is using the synchronous API (`StringSet`), and is being loaded by 10 threads concurrently. This will present no appreciable challenge to SE.Redis - it works just fine here. I *suspect* that it genuinely is a timeout where the server has taken longer than you would like to process some of the data, most likely also related to the server's allocator. One option, then, is to simply *increase the timeout a bit*. Not a lot... try 5 seconds instead of the default 1 second. Likely, most of the operations are working very fast anyway.

With regards to speeding it up: one option here is to *not wait* - i.e. keep pipelining data. If you are content not to check every single message for an error state, then one simple way to do this is to add `, flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget` to the end of your `StringSet` call. In my local testing, this sped up the 1M example by 25% (and I suspect a lot of the rest of the time is actually spent in string serialization).

The biggest problem I had with the 10M example was simply the overhead of *working with the 10M example* - especially since this takes huge amounts of memory for both the `redis-server` and the application, which (to emulate your setup) are on the same machine. This creates competing memory pressure, with GC pauses etc in the managed code. But perhaps more importantly: *it simply takes forever to start doing anything*. Consequently, I refactored the code to use parallel `yield return` generators rather than a single list. For example:

```
    static IEnumerable<Person> InventPeople(int seed, int count)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            int f = 1 + seed + i;
            var item = new Person
            {
                Id = f,
                Name = Path.GetRandomFileName().Replace(".", "").Substring(0, appRandom.Value.Next(3, 6)) + " " + Path.GetRandomFileName().Replace(".", "").Substring(0, new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()).Next(3, 6)),
                Age = f % 90,
                Friends = ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(n => appRandom.Value.Next(1, f)).ToArray()
            };
            yield return item;
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<T> Batchify<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
    {
        var list = new List<T>(count);
        foreach(var item in source)
        {
            list.Add(item);
            if(list.Count == count)
            {
                foreach (var x in list) yield return x;
                list.Clear();
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in list) yield return item;
    }
```

with:

```
foreach (var element in InventPeople(PER_THREAD * counter1, PER_THREAD).Batchify(1000))
```

Here, the purpose of `Batchify` is to ensure that we aren't helping the server too much by taking appreciable time between each operation - the data is invented in batches of 1000 and each batch is made available very quickly.

I was also concerned about JSON performance, so I switched to JIL:

```
    public static string ToJSON<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return Jil.JSON.Serialize<T>(obj);
    }
```

and then just for fun, I moved the JSON work into the batching (so that the actual processing loops :

```
 foreach (var element in InventPeople(PER_THREAD * counter1, PER_THREAD)
     .Select(x => new { x.Id, Json = x.ToJSON() }).Batchify(1000))
```

This got the times down a bit more, so I can load 10M in 3 minutes 57 seconds, a rate of 42,194 rops. Most of this time is actually local processing inside the application. If I change it so that each thread loads the *same* item `ITEMS / THREADS` times, then this changes to 1 minute 48 seconds - a rate of 92,592 rops.

I'm not sure if I've answered anything really, but the short version might be simply "try a longer timeout; consider using fire-and-forget).

Comment: Thank you very much Im surely going to try it now - Also -  where is the settings for increasing the timeout ? in the *.conf file ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir this one version - includes many of the things I was talking about: http://pastie.org/9168040, and shows how to change the timeout (you can also do that by changing the string to `"localhost,syncTimeout=5000"`)

Comment: Marc ! it worked ! also , prior to your code , the CPU was very high _without_ any IO writs , so the memory ran out of space real quick ( i only left with 100mb) , **but** now - after your code , it is much better optimized  , the memory wasn't full , and the SSD worked in order to release pressure from memory.look at the graphs --http://i.stack.imgur.com/OdsZi.jpg

Comment: Marc , since I have a question regarding  Batchify  ^^ , I could've asked it here in comments , but since i believe it can help others, i decided to ask it as a different question. can you _please_ shed a light [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626695/batchify-long-linq-operations) ? my question is pretty simple , where/how does optimization kicks in ?

Comment: @MarcGravell do you have Cache interface with that kinda of speed.

Comment: @IamStalker can you be more specific? Because in the general case: the speed of light is a problem

Comment: @MarcGravell yes. and lol. In your example you are using Redis Database. Is it persistable or it is a simple multithreaded client cache?
And how can I make it not persistable?

Comment: @IamStalker define "persistable" in this context? persistable where? I know comments aren't amenable to detailed explanations, but it isn't clear to me *exactly* what you are asking, and the "exactly" matters a lot here

Comment: @MarcGravell let me be more accurate in my explaining, I need Redis cache model, I'm using the ServiceStack.IRedisClient - does your implementation is the same as the one I mentioned above? Or your `IDatabase` is Threadsafe? (Forget about persistance)

Comment: @IamStalker yes the api exposed by se.redis is fully thread safe; the expected usage is that a single multiplexer is reused between concurrent requests etc - very parallel. Two concurrent callers do not block each other: the two requests are pipelined and the results made available to each when the come back.

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks that exactly the thing I was needed for.