# Batchify long Linq operations?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I asked a question and got answered [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23606749/859154) about  performance issues which  I had a with a *large* collection of data. (created with linq)

ok , let's leave it aside.

But one of the interesting (and *geniusly*) optimization -  suggested by Marc - was to `Batchify` the linq query.

```
/*1*/ static IEnumerable<T> Batchify<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
/*2*/    {
/*3*/      var list = new List<T>(count);
/*4*/      foreach(var item in source)
/*5*/         {
/*6*/           list.Add(item);
/*7*/           if(list.Count == count)
/*8*/             {
/*9*/               foreach (var x in list) yield return x;
/*10*/              list.Clear();
/*11*/            }
/*12*/        }
/*13*/      foreach (var item in list) yield return item;
/*14*/    }
```

> Here, the purpose of Batchify is to ensure that we aren't helping the
>   server too much by taking appreciable time between each operation -
>   the data is invented in batches of 1000 and each batch is made
>   available very quickly.

Now , I understand *what* it is doing  , but I *can't* tell the difference since I might be missing the way it actually works. ( *sometimes you think you know something...till...*)

OK , back to basics :

AFAIK , Linq works like this chain –:

[image]

So, we can't start enumerating *till* the result of `select` in   :

```
Where-->OrderBy-->Select
```

was accomplished.

So basically i'm *waiting* for `select` to have *all* correct data (*after* `where` , after `orderby`), and *only then*   - my code can touch those values. (yielded from the `select`)

But according to my understanding of Marc's answer , it seems that there is a gap between those `yields` which allows other resources to do something... (?)

If so , then between each iteration of `#4` , after line`#9` , there is a time for CPU to do something else ?

**Question**

- Can someone shed a light please ? how does this work ?

---

nb

I already know that( for example) `select` is nothing but:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource,TResult>
 (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,TResult> selector)
{
   foreach (TSource element in source)
       yield return selector (elem![enter image description here][3]ent);
}
```

But if so , my code can't touch it till all values ( after `where` , `orderby`) were calculated...

## edit :

For those who ask if there's difference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Ojw.jpg

**2** seconds for **1M** items. 
**9** seconds for **5M** items.

(ignore the second line of time , (extra console.write line).)
[image]

here it is for 5m list : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DflGR.jpg ( the first one is withBatchify , the other is not)

[image]

Comment: I Love questions with images. It helps a lot the reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Important: the image shown includes `OrderBy`: you should note that this *breaks* batchify here, because `OrderBy` is a buffered operator. The batchify method I showed is intended for non-buffered spooling streams.

In the context in which I used it, the origin (before the batchify) was an iterator block that did lots of things involving object creation and pseudo-random number generators on each iteration. Because the code in question was timing sensitive, what I did *not* want to do was to introduce a reliable pause (for the CPU work of creating each item) between each call to the store. This was in part to emulate the original code, which created all the objects up front, and was in part because I understand how SE.Redis handles socket work.

Let's consider the behaviour without `Batchify`:

- create an item (CPU work) and yield it
- send it to the store (network IO)
- create an item (CPU work) and yield it
- send it to the store (network IO)
- create an item (CPU work) and yield it
- send it to the store (network IO)
- ...

In particular, this means that there is a predictable pause between store requests. SE.Redis handles socket IO on a dedicated worker thread, and the above could quite easily result in high packet fragmentation, especially since I was using the "fire and forget" flag. The writer thread needs to flush periodically, which it does when *either* the buffer hits a critical size, *or* there is no more work in the outbound message queue.

Now consider what batchify does:

- create an item (CPU work) and buffer it
- create an item (CPU work) and buffer it
- ...
- create an item (CPU work) and buffer it
- yield an item
- send it to the store (network IO)
- yield an item
- send it to the store (network IO)
- ...
- yield an item
- send it to the store (network IO)
- create an item (CPU work) and buffer it
- ...

here you can hopefully see that the CPU effort between store requests is **significantly** reduced. This more correctly mimics the original code where a list of millions was created initially, and then iterated. But additionally, it means that there is a very good chance that the thread creating outbound messages can go *at least as fast* as the writer thread, which means that the outbound queue is unlikely to become zero for any appreciable time. This allows for *much* lower packet fragmentation, because now instead of having a packet per request, there's a good chance that multiple messages are in each packet. Fewer packets generally means higher bandwidth due to reduced overheads.

Comment: Couldn't ask for more. Thank you. (p.s. it's my bad not to mention IO context , but it was due to my misunderstanding that Batchify was invented to solve IO delay interval).

Answer (score 0):

I know this solution was posted by a user probably more knowledgeable than me, but frankly, in your example, it does not do *anything*. The real killer in your last post was the fact that you used a `List<>` to actually *create* 10M entries *in memory* before starting the foreach loop on this materialized collection. Now you are using an `IEnumerable<>` which does not create 10M simultaneously in memory, but one after another (maybe more if parallel). The Batchify method is nice... but if you skip it, it should work just the same. Best case, it's a micro optimization.

Comment: Marc solved the 10m thing via that EACH TASK is creating **its own** list. this is regarding to the fact that _nothing was even started_ because we calculated 10m _at first place_ (which is a bad idea). it still doesn't answer the question above. ( im not the downvoter)

Comment: Can you post a self contained example please? Using Batchify to produce way better results than the same without Batchify? Because frankly, you *don't* seem to understand what made the last answer work.

Comment: again - **All im trying to understand** (pretty simple) is what marc said and **how** does it work —— : _Here, the purpose of Batchify is to ensure that we aren't helping the server too much by taking appreciable time between each operation - the data is invented in batches of 1000 and each batch is made available very quickly._

Comment: How about you *ask Mark in a comment then*? Because if I tell you it does not do what you think it does, you won't believe me anyway.

Comment: I thought about it  , (asking in comments) but explaining how i see things , and to explain how it actually works , requires *more* than a section comment. since - one can use this knowledge of batchify in his own projects -  - it seems to me that a Question place is **more** appropriate than a comments place.

Comment: i know it's an optimization , but i don't understand how/where the optimization kicks in ( or maybe i got this whole thing wrong)... ( please let's not fight , _you won't believe me anyway_ is not a nice thing to say , not to mention — isn't true.)

Comment: Maybe you should leave it out, do another test and see by how much it optimizes. I can speculate a bit about page/cache misses but we really don't know what time we are talking about here, right?

Comment: (maybe i'm not clear here) - nvoigt , even if it saves 0.001ms  - i still want to learn how does it works , because i don't understand how bulk of (unfinished-list )items can be released to work .... I mean , currently - I think that the list must be 100% calculated in order to deal with a single item. and here  , it seems that I can do something with `n` items (while another `x` items are on the way)...and Im positive that I can't do nothing before(!) i have `(n+x)` - this is my problem of understanding.

Comment: It's called `deferred execution`, that's what you get with `IEnumerable`. But you got that already without Batchify. That's my point. Would you please test it? We can argue all day long, but in the end your compiler will decide who is right and who is wrong. If it saves some seconds I'm really interested in Marks answer to learn something new, but if it does not save any significant time, maybe you will understand.

Comment: ok, according to your prior problem of being "really slow", 20 or 22 seconds is kind of a micro optimization. Still, it's 10% and I'm interested in how it exactly works. My guess still stands, paging/caching. But we should ask Marc.

Comment: The scenario in which I used it did not involve the 10M entries in a list. I will explain more in an answer.

Comment: Additionally, as I have now explained in full detail, the intent here was two-fold: firstly, to mimic the performance behaviour original code (large list) as reasonably as possible at reduced cost, and secondly: to reduce packet fragmentation due to knowledge of how the network layer works in this specific scenario